# How to render a Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox form an array?

Tags: zend-form

I need to render a MultiCheckbox like below:

#### Wanted:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy[read_only]" value="1" /> Just for read only
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy[is_pulic]" value="1" /> Is public
</label>
```

How can I do that? I just can do with:

#### Unwanted:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy[]" value="read_only" /> Just for read only
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy[]" value="is_pulic" /> Is public
</label>
```

Thanks so much for any your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was nothing else in your form, or you didn't mind each form element having the same format, you could use `setElementsBelongTo($array)` which is a method on a `Zend_Form`.

You might also then have to use individual checkboxes to acheive the desired markup, so this may or may not work in your scenario.